# How to install magento 2 in ubuntu?

Tags: magento2

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

- Installation request for symfony/finder v3.4.4 -> satisfiable by
  symfony/finder[v3.4.4].
- symfony/finder v3.4.4 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version
  (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.

**Problem 2**

- Installation request for symfony/stopwatch v3.4.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/stopwatch[v3.4.4].
- symfony/stopwatch v3.4.4 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.0.4) does not satisfy that requirement.

**Problem 3**

- fabpot/php-cs-fixer v1.13.3 requires symfony/finder ^2.1 || ^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v3.4.4].
- Installation request for fabpot/php-cs-fixer v1.13.3 -> satisfiable by fabpot/php-cs-fixer[v1.13.3].

I am trying to install Magento2 in ubuntu. My installation directory under the /var/www/public.

Can anyone help me to solve this error!

Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 3 ways to install Magento 2.

> 1. **Install from the archive file:**

- First and easiest way is to download it from Magento download page
  https://www.magentocommerce.com/download
- You can choose from Full Release (ZIP with no sample data) and Full Release (ZIP with sample data) options and from zip, tar.gz and tar.bz2 options.
- Next, create the database.
- Install the setup wizard using `<yourhost>/<projectpath>`, i.e. **`http: //localhost/magento2`** (in my case).
- Provide the correct detail while running the wizard.

That's all.

> 2. **Install via Composer**

A composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP.

- First, you need authentication keys which can be obtained here, and
  you will need Magento account to login.

  Once logged in, go to "My Access Keys", enter some descriptive "Name"
  and generate the new set of keys.
- Next, enter this command in terminal:

.

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

When prompted, your public key is the username, and the private key is password.

- Next, create the database.
- Install the setup wizard using /, i.e. http:
  //localhost/magento2 (in my case).
- Provide the correct detail while running the wizard.

> 3. **Install via GitHub**

- Create an empty directory and run:

```
git clone git@github.com:magento/magento2.git .
```

then:

```
composer install
```

- Next, create the database.
- Install the setup wizard using /, i.e. http:
  //localhost/magento2 (in my case).
- Provide the correct detail while running the wizard.

**Note:** You must have the proper folder and file permissions to install Magento successfully.

Comment: Thanks Mohit ! information vary useful but its doesn't solve the my problem   . i am facing  this error when i am run "Composer Install " command.

Comment: Is composer installed in your server?

Comment: i am trying to install on my local machine.

Comment: Still you need to install composer if you want to install Magento using composer method.

Comment: If you don't want to use composer, then opt for th first method (Install from the archive file) for your installation process.

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't have much knowledge about it then it's better to install it using composer. This website contains better documentation for it: https://r4pt3r.github.io/2019/02/Installing-Magento-2.html

- Clone it from GitHub: git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git
- Try composer install
- May you get some errors most of them will be because of not installing PHP extensions. The error will mention those.
- Install all those extensions and try composer install once more.
- If all are okay you can see the setup of magento 2 in your localhost.

All these information are taken from https://r4pt3r.github.io/2019/02/Installing-Magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

How to install magento 2.3 on ubuntu 18.04 or mac ***without using composer*** (php-v 7.2.3)

1. go to `[https://magento.com/tech-resources/download][1]` select the magento version as 2.3
2. select or check the sample data included and download the zip file
3. go to web root folder and extract it in my case `/var/www/html/`
4. Provide full read write access 777 to the folder
5. hit the localhost url `http://127.0.01/<your extracted magento folder>/`
6. check for readiness and install all necessary missing extensions
7. login to phpmyadmin and create a database
8. fill all necessary details and entire installation process takes 20+mins

Answer (score 0):

**- Download Magento Project using composer**

composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.0

**- Install Magento 2 using the command**

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento240" --db-host="localhost" --db-name=magento240_db --db-user=root --db-password=admin --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Magento" --admin-email="admin@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"

**Install sample data modules:**

- Using composer:

1. Add dependencies to the `composer.json`:
   composer require magento/module-bundle-sample-data magento/module-widget-sample-data magento/module-theme-sample-data magento/module-catalog-sample-data magento/module-customer-sample-data magento/module-cms-sample-data  magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data magento/module-review-sample-data magento/module-tax-sample-data magento/module-sales-sample-data magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data magento/module-downloadable-sample-data magento/module-msrp-sample-data magento/module-configurable-sample-data magento/module-product-links-sample-data magento/module-wishlist-sample-data magento/module-swatches-sample-data magento/sample-data-media magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data --no-update
2. Run:
   composer update

- Using magento:

1. Deploy sample data:
   bin/magento sampledata:deploy
2. Enable sample data modules (it's important!):
   bin/magento module:enable Magento_CustomerSampleData Magento_MsrpSampleData Magento_CatalogSampleData Magento_DownloadableSampleData Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData Magento_BundleSampleData Magento_ConfigurableSampleData Magento_ThemeSampleData Magento_ProductLinksSampleData Magento_ReviewSampleData Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData Magento_SwatchesSampleData Magento_GroupedProductSampleData Magento_TaxSampleData Magento_CmsSampleData Magento_SalesRuleSampleData Magento_SalesSampleData Magento_WidgetSampleData Magento_WishlistSampleData
3. Remove old files:
   rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
4. Upgrade magento files:
   bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. Recompile files:
   bin/magento setup:di:compile
6. Do reindex:
   bin/magento indexer:reindex
7. Deploy static content:
   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy